# Enter every folder and do command (bash or awk or etc)

Tags: bash

I was searching the most efficient way to do this but somehow none of the answer could sitisfy me (because may be I am not that good to implement them).

So here is my problem, I want a script in bash which enter in every folder (in the actual path) and do a command. 
The names of the folder share some characters but nothing that you can state with a simple rule, so for the sake of the problem lets say the all of them have random names.

I was trying to do something like:

```
cd main_folder  
cd subfolder_1_a
   do something
cd ..
cd subfolder_2_b
   do something
... 
...
cd subfolder_n_z
   do something
```

then also I want to get if is possible, some characters of the name of the folder in this example I want to get the last letter (a,b ...z)

To be more clear in this part:

Inside subfolder_a I want to do a command like:

```
if a< 5
command
cd ..
cd subfolder_b
if b<10
command 
etc
```

Please I need some help! 
Thanks!

Comment: You say you're talking bash, but your shebang line (`#!/usr/bin/perl -s`) says something different.

Comment: Wouldn't `for dir in */; do something with $dir; done` be enough?

Comment: I am sorry Jo so, you are completely right forget about that...my mistake.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try (`sh` and thusly also `bash`)

```
for dir in */; do
    dir=${dir%/}
    yourcommand "$dir"
done
```

There's a related gotcha: When there are not directories in the current working directory, the loop will run once with `dir` set to `*`. In bash, you can work around by prepending `shopt -s nullglob`.

Edit: Maybe this helps you.

```
for dir in */; do
    cd "$dir"  # go to subfolder
    dir=${dir%/}  # remove trailing slash
    dir=${dir#subfolder_}  # remove "subfolder_" prefix (no error checking)

    # now do something inside the subfolder. The suffix following the
    # subfolder_ prefix is now stored in the variable "$dir"

    cd -  # go back to parent folder (more precisely, to last folder in history)
done
```

Comment: works perfectly. But what happen with the last part that I need.  Get some characters from the name of the actual subfolder (in the one that I am making commands). Is it possible?

Comment: @Nikko: You must be more explicit about what you want to get and what the pattern of your directory names is.

Comment: Until now we have:
Enter so subfolder_a
do some commands
#missing part
get the character "a" from the name of this folder.
do a command that involves this character "a"
next I want  to do the same with every subfolder

Comment: I don't get that. If your directories are named `subfolder_XXX`, then a `dir=${dir#subfolder_}` will remove the `subfolder_` prefix from the `dir` variable.

Comment: Ok, But I am talking after being inside the folder, I want to save the name of it, and then save the character "a" in this example, then it will finish there and go to the next one which will be subfolder_b ...inside this one, I want to grab now the "b" character and so on. I want this because that character gives me some information that I will use in the commands. Example

 cd  subfolder_a
 echo "a is the physical quantity for this"
 if a < 5 
 do this
 done

 cd subfolder_b
 the same thing.
 etc

Comment: @Nikko: Now this is *very* specific and a bit unclear. I've added a longer example. But you should really learn a bit about the shell generally before you ask more specific questions.

Answer (score 0):

You can try a simple for loop in BASH script:

```
for i in "folder1" "folder2" "folder3"
do
   cd "$i"
   pwd
done
```

Answer (score 0):

There may be some syntax issues but basically what it does is that for every entry in the main_folder directory, if the entry is a directory (meaning a folder) then run the command.

```
cd /to/your/main_folder
for i in *; do 
   if [ -d "${i}" ]; then 
      # do your commands for example move the directory to home
      mv "${i}" /home
   fi
done
```

Comment: if statement had quotes missing.

Comment: No, `for i in main_folder` does not do what you expect.

Comment: What does it do ? I have scripts using that in CentOS... http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/bash-loop-over-file/

Comment: It runs the loop exactly once, with `i` set to the string `main_folder`

Comment: Ah you are correct. My apologies. I have updated my answer. It should run fine when executed as an executable file.